# How to config activemq DB persistence to Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, configuration, jms, activemq-classic

I need steps to configure Active MQ persistence to Oracle database. I was reading some blogs but couldn't find a solid solution. Can someone please guide me as I am new when it comes to configuring Active MQs.

Thanks in advance.

Edit 1 -
I followed steps mentioned on official blog, but ended up getting below error.
URL : https://activemq.apache.org/how-to-configure-a-new-database

```
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 92 in XML document from class path resource [activemq.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 92; columnNumber: 48; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbcPersistence'. One of '{"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":jdbcPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":journalPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":kahaDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":levelDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":mKahaDB, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":memoryPersistenceAdapter, "http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core":replicatedLevelDB, WC[##other:"http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"]}' is expected.
```

Edit 2 -
I was able to achieve this. Now issue is messages are getting stored in DB as in BLOB format but I want them to be stored as in plain/text. Can someone please help?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by storing messages in the db as text? The jdbcPersistence store should not be accessed by other applications

Answer (score 0):

Messages have to be stored as a BLOB, since ActiveMQ supports many non-text formats bytes, map, object and stream message types.